# How to know traffic to a specific port in linux

Tags: linux, port, traffic, network-traffic

I am looking to find the traffic through a specific port for a time frame. For example, traffic through 3306 port for 10 seconds. Is there a way to find this information?

I see that "/sbin/ifconfig eth0 05" can be used to get information on total bytes but I am looking to find information about specific port's traffic.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you look at tcpdump (http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html)?

Comment: What information do you need? Amount of traffic, who is connected - what?

Comment: Unless you try to do that through programming, this kind of question does not belong here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -s 1500 port 3306
```

Comment: I tried tcpdump but there doesn't seem to be a way to monitor the port for certain amount of time (like 5 seconds).

@Jenny D: I am looking for amount of traffic for a port for certain time period.

Comment: Just use another process to send tcpdump a signal after 5 seconds.  Or make your own program using libpcap.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I can make the program 'sleep' for 5 seconds and use the same tcpdump command again.

Comment: @Rawkode : What if I want to see the raw-data sent over port 3306 ?

Comment: Use the 'src' parameter and set it to your local IP address

Comment: You can use the 'watch' command to do exactly what you want. Essentially 'watch -n 5 tcpdump -i eth0 -s 1500 port 3306'. See http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo iftop -P -n -N -m 10M -f 'port 3260'
```

- -P display ports
- -n no hostname lookup
- -N display ports not service names
- -m limit for bandwidth scale
- -f filter rule